# Use USB pen drive as HDD for Linux mint

Tags: linux, unix, usb, bootloader, linux-mint

I have already installed Linux mint to a USB pen drive.It is working,but slow. On a p4 2.8 Machine with 512 ram. Can i speed up this system? Any suggestions ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are 3 constrictions to why you may be receiving slow speed. 1 Is it one a USB 2.0 or 3.0 drive/port? This makes a major difference. 2 Processor speed. 3 The RAM, although 512 MB is fine only that much will still limit things such as pagefile size so that mint has to continually store data on the flash drive much like a hard drive as to storing it in the ram,therefore using resources to read/write to the flash drive and slowing your OS.